# JFrame Buttons and GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

Why are my constraints for my buttons not working? I looked at the Java Docs and am doing the same thing the tutorials are doing, but for me the buttons stay the same regardless of what gridx, y, width, or fill I use. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
class MyWindow
{
public static void main(String [] arg)
{
    MyJFrame f = new MyJFrame("My GUI 2015");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(10, 20);
    f.add(f.p);
}
}
```

and

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

public JPanel p;
JButton close = new JButton("close");
JButton drawing = new JButton("drawing");
JButton image = new JButton("image");
JButton browser = new JButton("browser");

public MyJFrame(String title) {
    super(title);
    p = new JPanel();
    buildButtons();
}

void buildButtons() {       
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.insets = new Insets(0,40,0,150);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    p.add(drawing, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    p.add(close, c);
    c.insets = new Insets(50,225,50,150);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    p.add(image, c);
    c.insets = new Insets(0,125,0,125);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 100;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    p.add(browser, c);
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you specify the LayoutManager eg `GridBagLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LayoutManager for the container is not specified in your current code (the default for a JPanel is FlowLayout). If you wish to use a GridBagLayout on the container, you must explicitly specify the LayoutManager:

```
p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//or
p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Comment: (+1), Also, read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples. The examples will also show you how to better structure your code so that the Swing components are created on the Event Dispatch Thread, which is something you should always do to prevent random errors.